# Convert List<T> to List<myType>

Tags: c#, asp.net

When calling any Convert function error apperars:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductionRecent>
```

Im trying to pass any list inside the function, determine which list it must be and converting it. Any Suggestions?

```
    public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, List<T> list)
    {
        if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<ProductionPending>))
        {                
            ConvertToProductionPending(dt, list);   // ERROR
        }
        else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<ProductionRecent>))
        {
            ConvertToProductionRecent(dt, list);   // ERROR
        }
        else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<MirrorDeployments>))
        {
            ConvertToMirror(dt list);   // ERROR
        }
        return list;
    }

    private List<ProductionPending> ConvertToProductionPending(DataTable dt, List<ProductionPending> list)
    {
          // do some stuff here
          return list;
    }

    private List<ProductionRecent> ConvertToProductionRecent(DataTable dt, List<ProductionRecent> list)
    {
        // do some stuff here
        return list;
    }
    private List<MirrorDeployments> ConvertToMirror(DataTable dt, List<MirrorDeployments> list)
    {
        // do some stuff here
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest creating multiple separate methods rather than trying to make this work with generics.

Comment: Returning a `List<T>` is completely useless if the method is meant to convert. The return type will still be generic and that is completely useless thing to do. Unless you didn't actually asked the real question and what you want is to generate different `List` of specific type based on the `Datatable` that is the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast before pass to your method:

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, List<T> list)
{
    if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<ProductionPending>))
    {                
        ConvertToProductionPending(dt, (list as List<ProductionPending>)); 
    }
    else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<ProductionRecent>))
    {
        ConvertToProductionRecent(dt, (list as List<ProductionRecent>));   
    }
    else if (list.GetType() == typeof(List<MirrorDeployments>))
    {
        ConvertToMirror(dt, (list as List<MirrorDeployments>));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Edit:

Also, if you're just returning the list without doing anything, you don't need the convert method at all, just cast like `List<MirrorDeployments> l2 = (list as List<MirrorDeployments>)`

If you're using C# 7, you could also use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching):

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(DataTable dt, List<T> list)
{
    switch(list)
    {
        case List<ProductionPending> pp:
            //pp is list cast as List<ProductionPending>
            break;
        case List<ProductionRecent> pr:
            //pr is list cast as List<ProductionRecent>
            break;
        case List<MirrorDeployments> md:
            //md is list cast as List<MirrorDeployments>
            break;          
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `ConvertToList<T>` which is not written in a generic way (it just has a section for each meaningful type `T`), just create three non-generic overloads `ConvertToList(DataTable dt, List<ProductionPending> list)`, `ConvertToList(DataTable dt, List<ProductionRecent> list)` and `ConvertToList(DataTable dt, List<MirrorDeployments> list)` as suggested in a comment to the question by mjwills.